# Kerberos Authentication and SQL Clusters

Tags: sql-server, clustering, kerberos

We are planning on building several SQL clusters.  I want to create an alias and have the alias point to the cluster name.  The purpose is so that in the future when we have to migrate application to a newer version of SQL server, a new cluster is spun up and we just repoint the alias to the new SQL cluster once the databases are migrated, thus avoiding the process of changing the connection string in each application.

However, my server admin is concerned that we may have issues with Kerberos authenticating.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: building several SQL clusters - Are you referring to Failover Cluster Instance (FCI) on top of Windows Server Failover Clustering?